# WPF Scrollable Timeline Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to build a timeline-like control for a project, but I have limited experience with WPF, and don't really know where to start. The requirements are fairly simple: I have an `ObservableCollection` of objects that have a timestamp property, and I need to be able to select one or more of them and drag them back and forth on a "timeline". All of the objects will be rendered the same size since there's no concept of a start/end time. Here is a mockup of what I'm trying to build:

[image: Timeline control mockup]

I've spent hours searching for examples or tutorials, but when I search for "timeline" controls most of the results address a completely different problem:

[image: Wrong timeline control]

Comment: One has to take a standard slider and override the `Thumb` control and style appropriately. I worked a month+ on a specialized slider for a cable company before they lost their funding and pulled the plug on the project. It is not a trivial task...so dive in on how to create controls and styling. It will take some time but you can do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than going with the classic override of the Thumb control, I threw together a quick framework based off your mockup:
ZIP: http://www.mediafire.com/file/fidg8ea88ofoki4/TimelineFramework.zip

VirusTotal: https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/7579b365749d07eb743643ab118de71c7dd09cb03df7a8b28fbf3cec816ff4cc/analysis/1484802709/ and https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/4899aa96234e1e69c4e935f7d692e46789d8b4b7a5afd4c354937ed921986b20/analysis/1484802463/

It's pretty basic in terms of WPF as it's mostly C# with little XAML, so you can probably figure it out real fast and then be on your way to adapting it for your specific needs.

In the demo app, it looks like this:
[image]
The blue bands are draggable, with the thick center line representing their true placement and the faded side blue making for a bigger grip to click on. Hovering over a band shows its placement in the Tooltip. Of course, you can restyle and adjust all the visuals to your needs.

Comment: @NeilThiessen No problem at all, good luck with your project!